# SwiftUI. isPressed animation with Button inside another Button

Tags: swiftui

I have ScrollView with LazyVStack. The Stack has ForEach which generate buttons as row. Each Button has inside Text and small button.

I've created two ButtonStyle:

```
struct RowButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .frame(height: 44)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      .background(Color.pink)
      .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14, style: .continuous))
      .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
      .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
  }
}

struct SmallButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .white : .blue)
      .padding()
      .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.yellow : Color.green)
  }
}
```

The main view code:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      LazyVStack(spacing: 6) {
        ForEach(dataTypesArray, id: \.self) { each in
          Button {
            print("on parent")
          } label: {
            HStack {
              Spacer()
              Text(each)
              Spacer()
              Button {
                print("on child")
              } label: {
                Text("Tap")
              }
              .buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle())
            }

          }
          .buttonStyle(RowButtonStyle())
        }

      }
      .padding(.horizontal, 8)
      .padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
  }
```

So I am using buttons because I need press animations.
When I tap on RowButtonStyle animation works perfect. But when I tap on small button configuration.isPressed animation calls twice for parent button(RowButtonStyle) and for small button(SmallButtonStyle) but I need only small button animation.
I tried to replace RowButtonStyle with gestures but the animation was not what I expected and there were problems with scrolling.

[image]

Comment: That is to be expected when you have a button inside of a button you should look into SwiftUI.Layout or play account with an HStack so you can put the buttons side by side.

Comment: ```
              .buttonStyle(SmallButtonStyle())
            }

          }
          .buttonStyle(RowButtonStyle())
```

Why are you using that modifier? Instead of using HStack or something else to build UI?